# Google Sheets' Lambda Function

Tags: google-sheets, lambda

Can someone help me figure out how Google Sheets' inbuilt Lambda function works? There is no official documentation for it and the only information available is as in the below snapshot.

[image]

When using the lambda function as per the Help Box, Google Sheets is showing error as below.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Google officialy released today the lambda function, along with other functional programming related features. [Here is the official doc page](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718).

[A post in medium about it](https://medium.com/@r.murta/lambda-map-in-google-sheets-functional-programming-style-taking-over-the-world-d674be090170).

Answer (score -1):

Google officially released the lambda function and its helper functions, but not all users were supported at the time you posted your question, so the error message indicates that it is an unknown function.

See [support.google](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/12508718) for the LAMBDA function.